# Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'String'. Program of introducing LOL heroes

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged

        Select Case ListBox1.SelectedIndex

            Case 0
                TextBox1.Text = "For nearly twenty years, Fiddlesticks has stood alone in the easternmost summoning chamber of the Institute of War. Only the burning emerald light of his unearthly gaze pierces the musty darkness of his dust-covered home. It is here that the Harbinger of Doom keeps a silent vigil. His is a cautionary tale of power run amok, taught to all summoners within the League. Decades ago, there existed a powerful rune mage from Zaun - Istvaan. At the end of the fifth Rune War, he became one of the League's first summoners. Too much a prisoner to the old ways of magic, Istvaan stepped further and further outside the rules of conduct in the League. In what was ultimately his last match, his reach finally exceeded his grasp. Sealing himself inside the easternmost summoning chamber, he began incanting the most forbidden of rituals - an extra-planar summoning. What exactly happened inside that chamber remains unknown. No champion came to represent Zaun that day in Summoner's Rift. Only silence echoed back from repeated knocks on the chamber door. The first apprentice who entered was cut down immediately by an unearthly scythe. What few who followed and survived were driven mad by fear, mere husks of men gibbering about crows and death. Afraid of the evil even Istvaan could not control, the League sealed all exits to the chamber, hoping they could contain what they could not destroy. Years went by, but the wooden figure within never moved save to slay any foolish enough to enter. Seeing no recourse to reclaim the chamber, the Council instead devised a use for Fiddlesticks: executioner. While he comes to life and seemingly abides by the rules of summoning in the Fields of Justice, what he awaits inside his chamber is unknown. His unmoving face yields no clues, and his scythe stands ready to strike down any who stand before him. Those who say 'you have nothing to fear but fear itself' have not yet felt the crows."
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Resource1.FiddleSticks_0
                PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Resource1.FiddleSticks_8
                Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.Terrify
                Button2.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.Drain
                Button3.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.FiddlesticksDarkWind
                Button4.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.Crowstorm
            Case 1
                TextBox1.Text = "The most feared duelist in all Valoran, Fiora is as renowned for her brusque manner and cunning mind as she is for the speed of her bluesteel rapier. Born to House Laurent in the kingdom of Demacia, Fiora took control of the family from her father in the wake of a scandal that nearly destroyed them. House Laurent's reputation was sundered, but Fiora bends her every effort to restore her family's honor and return them to their rightful place among the great and good of Demacia."
                PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.Resource1.Fiora_0
                PictureBox2.Image = My.Resources.Resource1.Fiora_4
                Button1.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.FioraQ
                Button2.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.FioraW
                Button3.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.FioraE
                Button4.BackgroundImage = My.Resources.Resource1.FioraR
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListBox1.Items.Add("FiddleSticks")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Fiora")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("Fizz")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form2.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = My.Resources.Resource1.Teriffyskill
    End Sub
```

Why is it not working?
This is the part where "it" shows
`My.Resources.Resource1.Teriffyskill`
and it says

> Value of type '1-dimensional array of Byte' cannot be converted to 'String'.

Comment: Welcome to [so], you may check [ask] first.  Moreover, you may need to provide your resources, we won't know what is your `Teriffyskill`.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the Teriffyskill property you defined in My.Resources.Resources1 is defined as a Byte array. If you want to be able to assign the value to a string value like Form2.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL, then you will need to change the definition of Teriffyskill to a string or cast it when you assign it to the URL

So instead of

```
 Dim Teriffyskill As Byte()
```

You would define it as

```
Dim Teriffyskill as String
```

Or you could cast it like so in your Button1 Click handler.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(My.Resources.Resource1.Teriffyskill)
End Sub
```